# Laravel 4 seed database table with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4

Usually we create a database seed file like this to seed a database table:

```
class UsersSeeder extends DatabaseSeeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $users = [
            [
              'email' => 'mymail@mail.com',
              'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
              'name' => 'Admin'
            ]
       ];

       foreach ($users as $user) {
         User::create($user);
       }
    }

}
```

But how can we seed table with relationship? For example, table users with table memberdetail:

**Users Table:**

```
id, email, password, name
```

**memberdetail table:**

```
id, userid, gender, address, dob
```

memberdetail table's `userid` column will show the `id` which links to the id on users table.  How can we seed these 2 tables?

Thank you.

Comment: what is model for `memberdetail` table? share relationship as well.

Comment: Anam, I have updated the question for better explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a model called `MemberDetail`.

```
    class UsersSeeder extends DatabaseSeeder {

        public function run()
        {
            $users = [
                [
                  'email' => 'mymail@mail.com',
                  'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
                  'name' => 'Admin'
                ]
           ];

           foreach ($users as $user) {
             $user = User::create($user);

             $memberDetail = new MemberDetail;
             $memberDetail->userid = $user->id;

             // Fill up gender, address, dob
             // i am not sure what data you have for gender, address and dob.
             $memberDetail->gender = 'Male';
             $memberDetail->address = 'Australia';
             $memberDetail->dob = '2014-01-08';
             $memberDetail->save();
           }
        }

}
```